# Supplementing rather than overriding vars?

Tags: ansible-inventory

In deploying servers, we have a common "users" role, with a variable of the same name.

The problem is that in our inventory, that variable of course gets clobbered by any subordinate group variable definition. So if we have:

*Inventory files*

```
all/
  users.yml
  foo/
    users.yml
```

and `users` has a gid, username, etc. list in it, when deploying a server with role `foo`, we get only the users created in `all/foo/users.yml`.

Is it possible to make the variable something that gets appended, rather than over-written?

Comment: Looks like this may be the answer: https://serverfault.com/questions/685673/appending-to-lists-or-adding-keys-to-dictionaries-in-ansible

Comment: Nope, I get an error, "recursive loop detected in template string" with the above.